# Why the statement cursor.getstring(cursor.getcolumnindex("id")) retrieves wrong data from database?

Tags: database

The statement cursor.getstring(cursor.getcolumnindex("id")) does not retrieve the correct data related to "id", instead wrong data is retrieved from database? What is the reason? How to solve this problem?

Sample Code is given below: 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/" + code);

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor.getCount() >= 1) {

cursor.moveToFirst();

String convValue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                                                                outText.setText(String.valueOf(convValue));

}
else {

throw (new Exception("code invalid"));

}

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: An example of what your database content looks like would also be helpful.